# PayPal Subscriptions: Adjustings value for a discount

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

How can I give discount on Subsciptions?

I have integrated PayPal API for subscriptions to my website and its working well. Please guide me how to provide discount feature for subscriptions in PayPal. For example, my subscription is 2 USD/Month with a setup fee of 100USD, now I want to offer 50 percent discount on setup fee..

Right now for the time being I have created multiple plans with different rates according to the discount I want to give and then user puts the voucher code of my website and my server redirects it to the relevant plan ID. But I am looking for a better solution.

Here is an image of a JS SDK Subscribe button:

[image: scenerio]

What I doing for this is I am destroying the whole instance and creating it again after voucher entry, but I would like to update its values dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a Plan object that describes the amount(s) you want to charge. This is how subscriptions work.

When creating a subscription, in addition to specifying a Plan ID, you can also additionally provide a Plan object with values to override. See the documentation for the [create subscription request body](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions-create-request-body), which has a `plan` key name.

So to make this concrete, for your case when creating the subscription `plan.payment_preferences.setup_fee` could contain an adjusted value.

Comment: Lemme check this,,, Thanks i will get back to you

Comment: OK i got it... I will tick mark the answer and pray for you if my test will be successful Thanks :D And also update the question with the answer as well :D

Comment: Your answer is good, but the problem emerges where i want to update the payment info at runtime... which i think paypal smart button instance doesn't allow... :'(

Comment: I am including an image of my scenario...

Comment: the image has been uploaded...

Comment: The createSubscription function is called when the button is clicked. When you pass the plan_id , pass any other subscription creation parameters in that same request object.